# nodejs mongoose find query with parameter doesn't work, return null

Tags: node.js

I have this route :

```
router.get('/api/sellOffer/seller/:sellerId', sellOfferController.getAllSellOffersBySellerId);
```

Pointing there :

```
exports.getAllSellOffersBySellerId = (req, res, next) => {
  SellOffer.find({
    sellerId : req.params.id,
  }).then(
  (sellOffers) => {
    res.status(200).json(sellOffers);
  }
  ).catch(
    (error) => {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: error
      });
    }
  );
};
```

And retriving me this (status 200 OK) :

```
null
```

However I have this in my DB :

```
_id:615ea0157d3bb20016da036c
price:800
sellOfferAccept:true
productId:"615ea0147d3bb20016da036a"
sellerId:"615b1e1bfde0190ad80c3477"
couponDownloaded:false
createDate:2021-10-07T07:21:57.234+00:00
__v:0
```

I've tried many way of writing the request :

```
https://hiddenlink/api/sellOffer/seller/?id=615b1e1bfde0190ad80c3477
```

```
https://hiddenlink/api/sellOffer/seller/?sellerId=615b1e1bfde0190ad80c3477
```

None work. Any idea please ?

Thanks a lot for any anwser and have a good day ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using express,

`/api/sellOffer/seller/:sellerId` resolves to `/api/sellOffer/seller/615b1e1bfde0190ad80c3477` - it doesn't use query parameters.

Also, consider whitelisting values when returning the JSON response, you don't want some accidental extra data being returned.

Comment: Oh, ok, so how do I do to set my parameter sellerId in request parameter ? Because I need it to do my request... thanks for the tip also :)

Comment: Using fetch, you could do:

`fetch(\`https://hiddenlink/api/sellOffer/seller/${id}\`)`

Comment: Well I'm trying in postman for example : 

https://link/api/selloffer/seller/615b1e1bfde0190ad80c3477

And it retrieves empty data :
[]

Comment: Oh wait I tried this : https://link/api/selloffer/seller/615b1e1bfde0190ad80c3477?sellerId=615b1e1bfde0190ad80c3477
And it worked, but I dont want this kind of link and justt want to set the sellerId in the params ....

Comment: Nevermind, I answered my own question... just to take off the ":sellerId" in the link...